# Issue in folder creation within C:\cygwin64\home\ after cygwin setup

Tags: shell, cygwin

I was trying to install cygwin on my system, but even after the setup is complete any folder with the user name is not being created at location C:\cygwin64\home in my system.So subsequently .bashrc, .bash_profile and other files that are created within the a folder at location C:\cygwin64\home is not bein created.

Answer (score 0):

The software installs where you tell it to. You can find where it was installed by rerunning the correct setup exe and clicking Next until you get to the "Select Root Install Directory" screen. On that screen will be where Cygwin was installed.

Comment: yes, what i mean to say is that within cygwin folder, within home folder, a folder with the username for example "hp" is not being created.

Comment: You should update your question to be as explicit as possible. That's two very different problems.